# python pypyodbc won't select data

Tags: python, sql-server, select, odbc

I think I'm going mad here... again :). I'm trying to do the most simple thing on the planet and it doesn't work for some reason unknown to me. I have a python script that connects to a mssql database using pypyodbc and does stuff. when I insert data into the database, it works. when I try to extract it, it fails miserably. what am I doing wrong?

```
import pypyodbc as mssql

msConnErr = None

try:
    msconn = mssql.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=database;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=True')
    print('Source server connected')
    srcCursor = msconn.cursor()
except:
    print('Source server error')
    msConnErr = True

srcCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM schema.table")
srcResult = srcCursor.fetchall()
print(srcResult)
```

the connection works as I'm being given a successful message. I can also see my script using sql server management studio being connected to the correct database, so I know I'm working in the right environment. the error I'm getting is:

```
UndefinedTable: relation "schema.table" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM schema.table
```

the table exists, I must specify the schema as I have the same table name in different schemas (data lifecycle). I can extract data from it using sql server management studio, yet python fails miserably. it doesn't fail to insert 35 million rows in it using the same driver. no other query works, even SELECT @@VERSION fails, SELECT TOP (10) * FROM schema.table fails etc. ...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

basically, I had a piece of code that would rewrite the srcCursor variable with another connection, obviously that relation wouldn't be present on another server. apologies!